# WPF How to change the color of a gridviewcolumn

Tags: c#, wpf

To preface the bulk of the question, I've found several answers regarding CellTemplate and DataTemplate, as well as one setting HeaderContainerStyle, and none of them worked; results ranged from no change to a crash.

I'm trying to change the color of the first entry in each column for my listview (basically so the header for each column sticks out). Here's the most recent thing I've tried with no success. Any suggestions or advice are greatly appreciated.

```
<ListView Height="380" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="First" Width="60" >
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="Txt" Text="{Binding First}" Background="DarkBlue"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Last" Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Last}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Group" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Group}" />
                    </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: So you are trying to change color of _header_ of each column?

Comment: @Evk Yes, that's correct. Basically want the headers to be a soft blue, while the bulk of the listview remains white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the following code what you are looking for?

For the first row:

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Txt" Text="{Binding First}"/>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter TargetName="Txt" Property="Background" Value="DarkBlue"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

For the header:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="First" Width="60" >
    <GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue"/>
        </Style>
    </GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, and thank you for the answer! Unfortunately no, this doesn't seem to change the background of it at all.

Comment: You want to change the background of the header, not the first row?

Comment: Correct - in this instance the box with the pre-existing label "First"

Comment: Just see my appended answer. Is that what you want to achieve?